# looping through elements and using them as names for objects in python

Tags: python

```
for N_RECORDS in ['50k','50m','100m','200m','python']:
  eval("res_"+N_RECORDS) = spark.read.load("/tmp/xgb-rts/xgb_results_"+N_RECORDS+"_pos.csv")
  eval("res_"+N_RECORDS+"_neg")=spark.read.load("/tmp/xgb-rts/xgb_results_"+N_RECORDS+"_neg.csv")
```

I just want to create objects with the names `res_50k, res_50m, res_100m, res_50k_neg`, etc without doing it manually.

However, I keep getting an error

```
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
  File "<command-1997330779535506>", line 2
    eval("res_"+N_RECORDS) = spark.read.load("/tmp/xgb-rts/xgb_results_"+N_RECORDS+"_pos.csv"
```

How do I work around this?

Comment: Use a list or a dictionary to collect results.

Comment: Creating variable names dynamically is usually a bad idea.

Comment: use `exec` not `eval`

Comment: some example code would be helpful